# What does the D in DMCS stand for?

Tags: c#, mono, dmcs

So, I was reading about the [mono c# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/). I know what the purpose of the apps are, but I was just wondering what the abbreviations stand for. (Also what does gmcs, smcs and csc stand for?)

If I were to take a guess it would be (Something) Mono Compiler Service.

Comment: What did the docs have to say?

Comment: csc stands for C-Sharp Compiler.  I don't know about the others.

Comment: @HenkHolterman [Turns out the docs had the answer (indirectly).](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/#history)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I can surmise from the [documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/#history) (and is also in chronological order, earliest to latest):

- csc = **C** **S**harp **C**ompiler (from Microsoft)
- mcs = **M**ono **C**ompiler **S**ervice (or potentially **M**ono **C** **S**harp, but compiler service is spoken about elsewhere, and this compiler is actually written in C#).
- gmcs = Support for **G**enerics
- smcs = Support for **S**ilverlight (Moonlight)
- dmcs = Support for **D**ynamic

All the compilers also support additional things, but it appears as though the prefix of the compiler command-line name takes the dominant reason for the increase in version.

Comment: Great explanation. One thing you might want to add is that in modern versions of Mono there is only `mcs`. The `gmcs`, `dmcs` etc. are now just scripts that pass `-sdk:2` (gmcs) or `-sdk:4` (dmcs) to the mcs compiler. They are only included to not break build scripts that rely on them.

Comment: @AlexanderKöplinger I'll leave your comment to do the explaining :-)