# C#: In Command Line, how to link two class files without IDE like Visual Studio or MonoProj?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, ide

I need C# help from the experts out there.
I'm running my programs command line on Ubuntu. 
I have two Class files , Class A and Class B and I am trying to use Class A inside of Class B. 
I tried using the same namespace for both of them and including Class B in the header of Class A with my include System.xxx tags but I'm getting the following:

```
"TdFMain.cs(26,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Biker' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"
```

Does anyone know how I can get these two files working together? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile them together in a single turn:

```
gmcs <yourOptions> ClassA.cs ClassB.cs
```

The other option is to create a class library (.dll) from ClassA and include it when compiling ClassB:

```
gmcs <yourOptions> -r ClassA.dll ClassB.cs
```

Comment: how did you know the OP is using compiler called gmcs?

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the difference between gmcs and mcs ? Because I currently use mcs.

Comment: It is the same: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/ mcs just links to the latest version, so using mcs or gmcs makes no difference. It is even better to stick with mcs

Comment: @Psi thank you very much again. This little issue was driving me crazy!

Comment: @Lei Yang: because he is compiling on ubuntu, so it must be mono, and then gmcs was just a close assumption. @ eduardo glad I could have helped

Comment: if csc is short for csharp compiler, what is gmcs short for?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844595/what-does-the-d-in-dmcs-stand-for